# cluster solution for laboratory use

Tags: untagged

I'm going to build a cluster lab to test solutions and new applications for use in a larger cluster considered  to be highly available, scalable and fault tolerant. 
I want to know available open source solutions for such a cluster lab, any proposal or comment is appreciated.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few different solutions you could go with, depending on what you ultimately are trying to accomplish ( and I would even try to pick one that mimics the big one)

Most common might be [Beowulf Clusters](http://www.beowulf.org/overview/index.html). Other Parrellel ones are [PVM](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/pvm/pvm_home.html) or [MPICH2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/). Or you can even custom write some software that offloads task to a set of known machines. (I know Gentoo does this with distcc to distribute the task of compiling software).

I think it really depends on what you are trying to do / mimic.

For data intensive, check out [Apache's Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) it's an open-source project of utilities, file system and mapreduce implementation

Comment: My applications will be data-intensive and optimised to have high throughput typically for file I/O. Applications developed using MapReduce or for Content Delivery Networks are such ones.

Comment: Might want to check out Apache's Hadoop. Adding link in my answer